# Некорректная работа модального окна Bootstrap, окно сразу исчезает

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Использовал стандартное модальное окно Bootstrap, код тот же что и на сайте, и кнопки, и самого окна, также скрипт их.
Суть в том, что как только окно открывается, тут же закрывается, как если бы закрытие висело на эту же кнопку.
Думаю нет смысла кидать стандартный код, можете посмотреть на сервере [саму страницу](http://shaburakov.com/project/sportfresh/index.html#close), там внизу кнопка под футером. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой.
Никаких лишних обработчиков не висит, пробовал вставить на чистую страницу этого же сайта, проблема та же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас скрипты бутстрапа подключаются дважды подряд. Вторую строку надо убрать.

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```